# Number of ways of numbering an icosahedron

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, symmetry, solid-geometry

I was wondering how many ways a regular icosahedron (below) constructed from 20 congruent equilateral triangles could be numbered from 1 to 20. I'm going to be referring to the solid in 'layers', so the top and bottom layers are made of 5 triangles forming a pentagonal pyramid, whilst the middle layer is made of 10 triangles.

[image]

So far my thoughts are:

1. Choose 5 numbers for the top layer and permute as if arranging around a circle - $\binom{20}{5}\cdot4!$
2. Choose 10 numbers for the middle and permute as if arranging around a circle - $\binom{15}{10}\cdot9!$
3. Permute the remaining 5 numbers for the bottom layer - $4!$
   Which gives $\binom{20}{5}\cdot\binom{15}{5}\cdot(4!)^{2}\cdot9!$ in total.

However, I am unsure how to (or if I need to) further account for any symmetry in the solid, especially since it doesn't matter where I put the first number. Could someone explain please in detail if my steps are somewhat correct or if I'm completely wrong and how I would account for that symmetry?

Comment: Your answer of $\dfrac{20!}{5 \times 10 \times 5}$ does not look particularly plausible to me.  At first glance I would guess $\dfrac{20!}{20 \times 3}$ to deal with rotational symmetry (the location of the face labelled $1$ and its orientation) and half that if you want to take account of reflections too.

Comment: Sorry I'm still trying to grasp this, its a bit unintuitive to me. Could you please define what a reflection would mean in this case and how it would differ from just rotating the solid?

Comment: If you consider an equilateral triangle, as well as leaving it alone, it can be rotated onto itself by a third of a circle or two-thirds of a circle, giving three possibilities.  But, if you allow reflections, there are twice as many possibilities making six in total

Comment: How would the answer be derived if we were taking a layer by layer approach ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is very simple: there are $20!$ ways to assign the 20 distinct numbers to faces, but [the rotational group of the icosahedron has order 60](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_symmetry), so we divide by 60 to obtain the final answer of $\frac{20!}{60}=4.05×10^{16}$. If you consider reflections to be the same, this number must be divided by a further two, giving $\frac{20!}{120}=2.03×10^{16}$ numberings.

Comment: +1 though a justification of the $60$ might improve this further

Comment: @Henry done${}{}$